# Rust large array: thread 'main' has overflowed its stack

Tags: rust

New to Rust, and ran into this error `thread 'main' has overflowed its stack` for this code:

```rust
fn main() {
    const N: usize = 10_000_000;
    let mut a: [u8; N]= [1; N];
    a[0] = 0;
}
```

It is ok for `N = 1_000_000`. Is there a better way to allocate long array?

Comment: The stack tends to not like huge objects. Use a `Vec` instead, which will allocate the array on the heap and your problem will go away.

Comment: Nice! Vec solves the problem

Comment: To be more specific, `let mut a = vec![1u8; N];` fixed it. Because Vec is allocated in the heap, which can grow much larger.